# "Add New Constraints" why -16 on the left and right, and not 0?

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

Ive noticed since `Xcode 6` and the introduction of `iOS8` that when I go to pin a `UIView` type to fill the frame that the checkbox always has `-16` to the left and right, why is it not `0`. Because I want zero spacing. I was just wondering where does `-16` come from?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple suggest a margin inside a UIView of 16pt inside. Apple put this to prevent labels, images, etc.. in the edges of the screen. If you want to but in the edge you have two ways

1-. add the constraints to -16 usually they work, but sometimes don't

2-. uncheck constraint to margin, and you will have 0

This only happened on the main UIView

I recommend always uncheck 'constraint to margin' if you want the view on both edges